# Verify that if vectors $a$ and $b$ are nonzero, then vector $c$ = |$a$|$b$ + |$b$|$a$ bisects the angle between $a$ and $b$ if $c$ is not zero.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Verify that if vectors $a$ and $b$ are nonzero, then vector $c$ = |$a$|$b$ + |$b$|$a$ bisects the angle between $a$ and $b$ if $c$ is not zero.

Is this question asking me to use random numbers to verify, or variables? Because I tried setting $a$ = <$x$, $y$> and $b$ = <$m$, $n$> and the expressions got really complicated when finding the angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $$c= |a||b|\Big({a\over |a|}+ {b\over |b|}\Big)$$

Since ${a\over |a|}$ and  ${b\over |b|}$ are sides of the rhombus (both of the vectors have norm = 1) we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Why compute angles explicitly? Use the definition of dot product to show that the cosines of the angles formed by the two initial vectors and $c$ are equal.